# Embedding celery decorator inside a class

Tags: python, celery, decorator, django-celery

I am struggling to call the celery decorator in my class. My problem is my decorator counts "self" as an argument. Is there any way that I can call this decorator inside my class?
I would appreciate any help and thank you !

```
import numpy as np
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker="amqp://xx@localhost")

class arithmaticFnc():
    def __init__(self):
        self.seed = 8

    @app.task
    def add_num(self, x, y):
        return x + y 
        
-----------------

A = arithmaticFnc()
result = A.add_num.delay(2, 1)

result.get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a class-based task like this:

```
import numpy as np
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker="amqp://xx@localhost")

class ArithmeticTask(app.Task):
    def __init__(self):
        self.seed = 8

    def run(self, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
        return x + y 

app.register_task(ArithmeticTask())
        
-----------------

a = ArithmeticTask()
result = a.delay(2, 1)

result.get()
```

Comment: Trying it like this, python celery does not process the task since it is "Unregistered and of type None". Could it be an incompatibility with older celery version?

Comment: Not sure how this isn't registering unless the code above is not in your worker.  Can you please confirm that the worker has the code above?